# Twig: Output the value only once and return empty on subsequent calls

Tags: twig

```
{% if a %}
<span class="{{ active_class }}">A</span>
{% endif %}
{% if b %}
<span class="{{ active_class }}">B</span>
{% endif %}
{% if c %}
<span class="{{ active_class }}">C</span>
{% endif %}
{% if d %}
<span class="{{ active_class }}">D</span>
{% endif %}
```

How do i output `{{ active_class }}` value for the first call, and empty string for all subsequent calls using as little extra code as possible and without custom extensions.

Comment: Are you doing this within a loop?

Answer (score 0):

**You can clean up your active_class variable after using it**:

```
{% if a %}
<span class="{{ active_class }}{% set active_class = '' %}">A</span>
{% endif %}
{% if b %}
<span class="{{ active_class }}{% set active_class = '' %}">B</span>
{% endif %}
{% if c %}
<span class="{{ active_class }}{% set active_class = '' %}">C</span>
{% endif %}
{% if d %}
<span class="{{ active_class }}{% set active_class = '' %}">D</span>
{% endif %}
```

#### See [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/vffu0c)